# SQL Server 2008 archiving

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have been using SQL Server 2008 as the database for an windows desktop application. I am re-engineering the product and I might use SQL Server 2008 or MySQL going forward.

So I am thinking of a general solution for archiving. Is there something similar to SqlDump in SQL Server 2008? Presently I am not using an ORM, I might plan to use Entity Framework in the coming days.

Basically I want to remove the old entries and whenever report has to be generated, I have to recover it as well..

Also I have an issue here: what if the database schema changes? How do we restore the old database?

If there is no common solution i would appreciate the solution specific to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I would consider a design that does not require the use of "old data", if possible. Unless there is a huge data usage scenario, it might be prudent just to retain all relevant records. As far as this question, a particular use-case hasn't really been outlined .. for a "[standalone] desktop application" I would recommend against MySQL. SQL Server Express, SQLite, and Firebird function quite well in a "serverless"/embedded configuration.

Comment: OK.Let me give you a scenario.Lets keep it specific to SQL 2008.I want to archive the data on the user click in the UI,User can also select the date till when it has to be archived.After the archival the the rows has to be deleted(just for performance improvement).I should be able to transfer the archived DB to another PC and restore it there.The second scenario would be the schema change.What if the user tries to restore an old database with the old schema.how 2 handle this ?Also its a client server architecture.There r more than one components(clients)connecting to the server and to the DB.

Comment: Deleting rows will *not* "improve performance" for a correctly designed schema with reasonable numbers of rows. Also, disk space is relative cheap these days .. so don't introduce a problem unless it is a testable/provable case to worry about.

Comment: hmm .. i agree on that. but in my application it doesn't make sense to have an old data , say belonging to last year which is equivalent to 200,000 lines. I only need it during report generation and as a backup in case if i need to check anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic of archiving, in general, is too broad for this forum. But I'm going to put in my two cents. I have found that it is best to archive records (i.e. literally move records from one table to another) and oftentimes in a different database.

This handles the schema issue because you can modify the schema of the archive table and keep it in sync.

It also allows you to write specialized reports that actually include archived data as an option.

It further allows you the ability to setup the server architecture for your archive databases differently than your production databases. They don't even have to be on the same server. They don't even have to be linked. Building a .NET application to move rows from one database to another on regular intervals based on your needs would be pretty trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. WHat if i want to move the archived DB from one PC to another?

Comment: @user1687824: Well, if you leverage the disconnected approach I mentioned it shouldn't really be an issue. You simply need to be able to connect to the two SQL Servers on the network in some way.